# Modifying HTML of menus

Tags: blocks, theming, navigation

In my Drupal 7 template, this one line of code spits out all my menues:

```
<?php print render($page['header']); ?>
```

I want to remove extraneous wrapper tags from my menus; for example, Drupal 7 prints out one of my menus as:

```
<div id="block-menu-menu-top-menu" class="block block-menu">
    <h2>Top menu</h2>
    <div class="content">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="first leaf"><a href="/home" title="">Membership</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="/home" title="">Calendar</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="/home" title="">Newsletter</a></li>
            <li class="last leaf"><a href="/home" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to simplify it to something like:

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li class="first leaf"><a href="/home" title="">Membership</a></li>
        <li class="leaf"><a href="/home" title="">Calendar</a></li>
        <li class="leaf"><a href="/home" title="">Newsletter</a></li>
        <li class="last leaf"><a href="/home" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I remove unnecessary wrapper tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are template hints that work exactly with this, but you can place block.tpl.php and region.tpl.php (in modules/block/ and modules/system/ respectively) in the theme directory, and then use conditions to sort through which areas you want to be marked up the default way and regions you don't want to be marked up that much.

Comment: ah got it....i made a block--menu.tpl.php with the content `<?php print $content; ?>`.  That overwrote the /modules/block/block.tpl.php which contained all the extraneous div wraps.

Comment: John, @mrlostman.. I need to implement the same thing.. and I am a newbie to drupal.. but this doesn't worked for me.. Please help me..